# What is the type of IconButtons in Material UI in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I am currently making a sidebar by Material UI, Next JS with typescript. I plan to make a helper function to display items in the sidebar

```
// LeftSidebar.tsx

import {List,ListItem,ListItemButton,ListItemIcon,ListItemText,} from "@mui/material";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";

const SidebarItem = (text: string, icon: any) => {
  return (
    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
      <ListItemButton>
        <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={text} />
      </ListItemButton>
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

I would like to input <MailIcon /> as an argument for icon parameter.

However, I don't know what type should I write.

I have tried somethings like function, object but it didn't work.

May I know if there is any problem in my codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is `ReactElement` or `ReactNode`.
If you don't want accept `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `Fragment` - use more concrete type - `ReactElement`.
If yes - use `ReactNode`.

Unfortunately, you can't specify which component type the element renders.
However, if you definitely need that, you can achieve it like this:

```
import {
  ListItem,
  ListItemButton,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  SvgIconProps,
} from '@mui/material';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';

type SidebarItemProps = {
  text: string;
  Icon: ComponentType<SvgIconProps>;
};
const SidebarItem = ({ text, Icon }: SidebarItemProps) => {
  return (
    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
      <ListItemButton>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <Icon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={text} />
      </ListItemButton>
    </ListItem>
  );
};

const renderedSidebarItem = <SidebarItem text="some text" Icon={MailIcon} />;
```